# How does one add hours to a datetime in Apple Numbers?

Tags: iwork-numbers

I have one column that has a start date, and another column that has a duration field in hours. I cannot figure out how to add the hours to the datetime field.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
Starts+DURATION(0,0,thehours)
```

In full, my forumulate that converts the duration column into 5 hour work days is:

```
Starts+DURATION(0,0,FLOOR(DUR2HOURS(Duration),5)+MOD(DUR2HOURS(Duration),5)×24)
```

Comment: For users of german version of Numbers (iOS, ipadOS): formula `JETZT()+DAUER(0;0;-27;-92;0;0)` subtracts from now 27 hours and 92 minutes: if now = `26.04.20 20:37:17` result is `25.04.20 16:05:17`.